# Suddenly Ogre headers are not found (DEVELOPER_DIR changed with an Xcode update)

Tags: c++, xcode, ogre

I am developing an application on MAX OS X Mountain Lion with latest stable Ogre and the latest Xcode. I did all the basic tutorials, and everything went smoothly. After that I started to modify one of these tutorials and started to develop some own stuff in it. Still everything worked correctly. Then today I opened my project again, and the code doesn't compile and states that it can't find the Ogre headers. More specifically it can't find the first included Ogre header file, if I comment it out, then it goes to the next one, and so on.

I checked and the search paths are set good. My Ogre SDK is there where it is pointing to. Anybody has any clue why could this happen?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I checked all my Ogre projects and the error is present at all of them.

EDIT EDIT:

In Xcode at my framework, header, library search path I have this:

> /$(DEVELOPER_DIR)/SDKs/OgreSDK/...

If I put the whole path like this:

> /Users/< my user name >/OgreSDK/...

Then it compiles without error.

So my question is how can I set properly the "$(DEVELOPER_DIR)" in Xcode...and how could I modify it without knowing that I am modifying it?

Also I have to mention, that in SDKs folder I have a symlink which points to OgreSDK folder, which is at "/Users/< my user name >/"

Comment: What command is doing the building?

Comment: Where  are the headers on your system?

Comment: My headers are at /Users/<my user name>/OgreSDK/lib/release/Ogre.framework/Headers
I did not understand your first question I think tho...I just build it with Xcode when ever I want to test my app.

Comment: How do you know the include paths are correct? How can you change the include paths? Also, In the build log, what command does it say the build was built in response to?

Comment: Hi, I added some edit to my post, please check it out. Also how can I check the build log? Sorry I am new to Xcode.

Comment: I know next to nothing about XCode. I'm just going through the basic 'is it plugged in' type questions. It looks as though you've found the problem though.

Comment: oh, ok...thanks for helping! :)
Unfortunately I have no clue how to set this DEVELOPER_DIR properly...and mostly I have no clue how could I change it without knowing I am changing it :D...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, I write it down so it might help others.

The thing was, that when I shut down my Mac, I updated the Xcode and I forgot this. With that update the DEVELOPER_DIR no longer pointed to /Developer, they removed it and moved everything to /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer. So the solution is that you move your OgreSDK there, or you can make a symlink into that folder if you don't want to move it. Hope it helps!

Thanks for this hint to masterfalcon at the Ogre forum.
([My Ogre forum post with the same issue](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&p=489789#p489789))